# Rails3 gem 'nested_form' - how to make optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding the gem 'nested_form' to a Rails3 app.

It works fine if you want to add the associated record and you enter data.
But, I want the associated record to be optional = no data typed in.

**When I save the form, I get errors saying the associated record is missing required fields.**

Client Model:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
```

Client Form:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @client, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
...
        <h4>Primary Location (optional) ===========</h4>
        <%= f.fields_for :locations do |l| %>
            <%= l.input :name, :label => 'Name' %>
            <%= l.input :address1 %>
            <%= l.input :address2 %>
            <%= l.input :city %>
            <%= l.input :state %>
            <%= l.input :zipcode %>
        <% end %>
...
```

Client Controller:

```
  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.locations.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @client }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:reject_if` parameter to make sure the record with blank required fields gets rejected. For example:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, reject_if: proc { |l| l['name'].blank? && l['address1'].blank? }
```

Check out the documentation for more details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for